# Marge groups from one table if they have same element

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to marge Groups if they have same Element:

```
Group     Element
1         e1
1         e2
2         e1
2         e3
3         e4
3         e5
4         e5
4         e6
5         e7
```

The expected output is:

```
Group     Element
1         e1
1         e2
1         e3
3         e4
3         e5
3         e6
5         e7
```

Group 1 and 2 are merged by same element e1. Group 3 and 4 are merged by e5.

Comment: Assume another row with (2, e4) as values. Would you merge in this case groups 1, 2, 3 and 4 into one group?

Comment: Yes, if we had another row (2, e4), the groups 1, 2, 3 and 4 would be merged in one group.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
    min(`group`),
  `element`
from 
  `Table1`
group by `element`
order by `element`,`group`
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a6f6c/1)

Comment: are you sure its same result he want ?

Comment: The result of the query is:
`1 e1`
`1 e2`
`2 e3`
`3 e4`
`3 e5`
`4 e6`
`5 e7`

The error is at e3 and e6: `2 - e3` need to be `1 - e3`, and `4 - e6` need to be `3 - e6`.

Comment: From the SQL fiddle example (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cec4c/4), the error is at `4 e6`, which need to be `3 e6`.